# How to handle image not being downloaded

Tags: ios, nsdata

I want to handle the case where the download thread doesn't succeed to download the image from a URL, the following code doesn't seems to fit my purpose:

```
dispatch_queue_t DownloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Download Pic", NULL);
dispatch_async(DownloadQueue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:detailImageURL]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([imageData isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            detailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_available.jpg"];

        }
        else{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            detailImageView.image = image;
        }
    });
});
dispatch_release(DownloadQueue);
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?

Comment: If `dataWithContentsOfURL` fails, doesn't it return `nil`? I don't think it returns a `NSNull` object. Regardless, where precisely is it failing? The `NSData`? The `imageWithData`?

Comment: @Rob Yep is returning nil. So the if statement will never be executed only the else statement.

Comment: Also, you could contemplate using [`dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BCIIDGEC) so that you can query the `error` object, if you want diagnostic information about the nature of the failure.

Comment: @Rob, thanx, I used your comment to fix the issue. What you think about it?

Comment: Yep, that's an improvement. Great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rob, thanx, a workaround fix the issue:

```
dispatch_queue_t DownloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Download Pic", NULL);
dispatch_async(DownloadQueue, ^{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:detailImageURL]];
    if (imageData == nil) {
        detailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image_available.jpg"];

    }else{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            detailImageView.image = image;
    });
    }
});
dispatch_release(DownloadQueue);
```

Before getting in the `async` block, test if `NSData` is nil or not.